# where is systemctl command in redhat 6.6 64 bit OS?

Tags: redhat, command, systemctl

I was trying to run status of network by following commands.

```
sudo systemctl status network
```

However the system says systemctl command not found.

Comment: RHEL6 isn't systemd-based, it's (sadly) the last RHEL that uses old-style SYSV init scripts.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! service network status worked for me! I touched /etc/hosts and /etc/sysconfig/network file and need to restart network on rhel 6.6.

Comment: me trying start mongoDB worked when I was getting "systemctl not found". The following command worked: /etc/init.d/mongod start

Answer (score 9):

As MadHatter has said in a comment to your question, RHEL 6 doesn't use SystemD (of which `systemctl` is a part), but rather use SYSV init scripts.

As said by TessellatingHeckler, the closest equivalent would be the `service network status` command, but it's not quite the same.